# What did the "anteater-like creatures" cut from Star Wars look like?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

I have a *Star Wars* minutia question.

In an early version of the screenplay for the first film there were "anteater-like creatures" on the streets of Mos Eisley on Tatooine. From the "third draft, August 1, 1975" [[link]](http://whills.nu/4/sw5.html)

> ```
> ... Several robots 
> guide a small herd of anteaters down the street.
> ```

In the "revised fourth draft screenplay, March 15, 1976" [[link]](http://whills.nu/4/sw6.html), dated shortly before the start of principal photography on March 22, 1976:

> ```
> Ben and Luke leave the speeder-lot and walk down the dusty
> alleyway past a small robot herding a bunch of anteater-like
> creatures.
> ```

And in the [novelization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_From_the_Adventures_of_Luke_Skywalker), presumably based on that fourth draft screenplay:

> Leaving the main street, they turned down an alleyway and walked past
> a small robot herding along a clutch of creatures resembling
> attenuated anteaters.

The "anteaters" seemingly did not make it to being built or filmed, but their removal must have been a late cut. Other obscure details in this scene mentioned in the "revised fourth draft" screenplay did make it to film, including the landspeeder dealer w/ an "insect-like" head and the tall, "spindly legged beast" that walks past the camera in the foreground.

**My question**: have any concept drawings or mockups for the herding droid and/or anteaters come to light? Is there anything unattributed from the production of the orignal *Star Wars* that might fit this description? Any behind-the-scenes mention of this?

Caveat, I don't actually know for sure if the dates or specific text of the screenplays linked above are correct, but they *look* credible.

Comment: I wonder if these scenes ended up in the special editions version... the anteaters could be the kangaroo mouse like creature seen at about 19seconds into this clip... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDcP51tRWX8

Comment: @skyjack, it's possible, but seems unlikely. According to [this link](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Scurrier#Behind_the_scenes), those creatures were designed for the 1997 Special Edition by TyRuben Ellingson.

Comment: Is no-one going to comment "Funnily enough, a bit like anteaters"? What are we even doing, people.

Comment: Confirmed that the creatures are mentioned in the script draft in _The Art of Star Wars: Special Edition_, but without accompanying concept art.